# Handle divide by zero exception in this SSRS rdlc expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdlc

The following code is showing result as Nan% if values are zero:

```
=FORMAT(((Sum(IIF(Fields!flag.Value=1,CINT(Fields!area1.Value),0)))
/ (Sum(IIF(Fields!flag.Value=1,CINT(Fields!UnitArea.Value),0))) *100),"N") + "%"
```

Comment: Try using the custom code posted [here](http://williameduardo.com/es/development/ssrs/ssrs-divide-by-zero-error/). Then you just have to call the Quotation function in your tablix like this: `=FORMAT(Code.Quotation(Sum(IIF(Fields!flag.Value=1,CINT(Fields!area1.Value),0)),
Sum(IIF(Fields!flag.Value=1,CINT(Fields!UnitArea.Value),0))),"P0")`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid the divide by zero error here is to not create it in the first place! If you replace the 0 as second return value in the divisor Iif expression with a 1, then the problem goes away.

That said I think your whole expression could do with simplifying somewhat. If I read it correctly you want to determine the proportion of area1 within UnitArea but only when the value of flag is 1. The expression could be thus written:

```
=Format(
    Iif(
        Fields!flag.Value = 1,
        CInt(Fields!area1.Value) / CInt(Fields!UnitArea.Value),
        Nothing
    ),
    "Percent"
)
```

Note that I've dropped the multiplier and instead used the Format function to return the result of the division as a percentage (you could also simply further by removing the Format function entirely and handling the [formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220510.aspx) in the designer).

You don't have to layout the expression with indentation as I have, but the expression builder ignores the whitespace and it does make larger expressions easier to read, so I think its a good habit to get into.